Unable to load application.yml in map
In my micronaut microservice, I have some properties in application.yml and I want to load those in a map. I am using following code but the map is null. So, how to load properties in map?
application.yml
people:
  details:
    person1:
      id: id1
      name: name1
      dob: dob1
    person2:
      id: id2
      name: name2
      dob: dob2

loading properties:
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationProperties;
import java.util.Map;

@ConfigurationProperties("people")
public class TestProperties {

    private Map<String, TestDetails> details;

    public Map<String, TestDetails> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Map<String, TestDetails> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public static class TestDetails {
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String dob;

        // Getters and setters
    }
}

using properties:
@Singleton
public class TestClass {

    private final TestProperties testProperties;

    @Inject
    public TestClass(TestProperties testProperties) {
        this.testProperties = testProperties;
    }

    public Map<String, TestDetails> getMap() {
        /* I get null map here */
        return testProperties.getDetails(); 
    }
}


What is your question? Map is empty? Map is null?

@talex. map is null

@talex. I am using micronaut framework. not sprinboot.

The documentation seems to suggest you need to use the @MapFormat annotation: https://docs.micronaut.io/4.6.3/guide/#configurationProperties

Please note that you also may have to annotate TestDetails with @Serdeable when using Serde. BR
